# Entity Framework Code First error with testing project

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am using Entity Framework's code first approach and updating my database with changes to my DB model using the following command.

Update-Database -Script

This was all working very well until recently I added some connection strings in the App.Config for my testing application. Now when I run the update-database -script command I get the following error. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to suppress it? Thanks in advance.

Update-Database : The project 'MyProject.Tests' does not contain any migration contexts.

Comment: Looks like -projectname is what I was missing, something may have gotten screwed up in the project file or something that changed the precedence of the projects because when unloading the testing project I found that it gave the same error for a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check on you Packet Manager console that the Source Project is the same where the Migrations Folder exists.

Comment: Is there a command you can use from the console to find out? Thanks for the input.

Comment: On the console are two combo boxes. One for the NuGet package source and another for the Project that will use as main.

Comment: Brilliant! I can't believe I didn't see those :|